# How to read a text file of numbers and turn it into a 40x40 list?

Tags: python, list

I have a text file like this:

```
1100111100111100111100111100111100111100
1100111100111100111100111100111100111100
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1100111100111100111100111100111100111100
1100111100111100111100111100111100111100
1100111100111100111100111100111100111100
1100111100111100111100111100111100111100
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1100111100111100111100111100111100111100
1100111100111100111100111100111100111100
1100111100111100111100111100111100111100
1100111100111100111100111100111100111100
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1100111100111100111100111100111100111100
1100111100111100111100111100111100111100
1100111100111100111100111100111100111100
1100111100111100111100111100111100111100
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1100111100111100111100111100111100111100
1100111100111100111100111100111100111100
1100111100111100111100111100111100111100
1100111100111100111100111100111100111100
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1100111100111100111100111100111100111100
1100111100111100111100111100111100111100
1100111100111100111100111100111100111100
1100111100111100111100111100111100111100
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1100111100111100111100111100111100111100
1100111100111100111100111100111100111100
1100111100111100111100111100111100111100
1100111100111100111100111100111100111100
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

How do I turn that into:

```
[
    [1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0],
    [1100111100111100111100111100111100111100],
    [0000000000000000000000000000000000000000],
    [0000000000000000000000000000000000000000],
    [1100111100111100111100111100111100111100],
    [1100111100111100111100111100111100111100],
    [1100111100111100111100111100111100111100],
    [1100111100111100111100111100111100111100],
    [0000000000000000000000000000000000000000],
    [0000000000000000000000000000000000000000],
    [1100111100111100111100111100111100111100],
    [1100111100111100111100111100111100111100],
    [1100111100111100111100111100111100111100],
    [1100111100111100111100111100111100111100],
    [0000000000000000000000000000000000000000],
    [0000000000000000000000000000000000000000],
    [1100111100111100111100111100111100111100],
    [1100111100111100111100111100111100111100],
    [1100111100111100111100111100111100111100],
    [1100111100111100111100111100111100111100],
    [0000000000000000000000000000000000000000],
    [0000000000000000000000000000000000000000],
    [1100111100111100111100111100111100111100],
    [1100111100111100111100111100111100111100],
    [1100111100111100111100111100111100111100],
    [1100111100111100111100111100111100111100],
    [0000000000000000000000000000000000000000],
    [0000000000000000000000000000000000000000],
    [1100111100111100111100111100111100111100],
    [1100111100111100111100111100111100111100],
    [1100111100111100111100111100111100111100],
    [1100111100111100111100111100111100111100],
    [0000000000000000000000000000000000000000],
    [0000000000000000000000000000000000000000],
    [1100111100111100111100111100111100111100],
    [1100111100111100111100111100111100111100],
    [1100111100111100111100111100111100111100],
    [1100111100111100111100111100111100111100],
    [0000000000000000000000000000000000000000],
    [0000000000000000000000000000000000000000]
]
```

The code I have tried is

```
content = open('filename').readlines;
for line in content:
    for c in line:
        if c in "\n":
```

Comment: @RobertHarvey guess I am saying it wrong. I would like to turn that huge chunk of number into something like, list = [ [1,1,1,1,...,0,0,0...], [1,1,1,1,...,0,0,0...],[1,1,1,1,...,0,0,0...],[1,1,1,1,...,0,0,0...],[1,1,1,1,...,0,0,0...],...,[1,1,1,1,...,0,0,0...],[1,1,1,1,...,0,0,0...]]

Comment: @Akavall: `.split('')` doesn't work in Python, does it? Anyway, `map(int, line)` should do the trick.

Comment: @minitech, Yes. I've seen it right after I posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```py
with open('filename') as fp:
    data = [[int(c) for c in line.strip()] for line in fp]
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
def split_up(line):
    return [int(ele) for ele in line.rstrip()]

with open('yourfile.txt') as f:
    your_list = [split_up(line) for line in f]
```

Here is minitech's answer, that he suggested to me in the comments:

```
with open('yourfile.txt') as f:
    your_list = [map(int, line.rstrip()) for line in f]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
file = open('test.txt')
matrix = []
for line in file.readlines():
    num_list = []
    for num in line:
        if num == '\n':
            break
        else:
            num_list.append(int(num))
    matrix.append(num_list)

print matrix
```

Comment: this is good as well, i understood it more lol. thanks!